# Hold an imagesc on matlab gui

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface

I have a little mess with a GUI developed on Matlab. Basically, I have two axes, one to plot a bitmap I want to keep all the time and another one to do some ordinary plots. My problem is that when I try to do any plot on the second axes, the image on the first one disappears and the axis get restarted. I tried to plot over the image and it remains on the figure (only shifts because the axis change once the previous image is gone).

Any idea aout what is happening? By the way, it is for a chromatic tuner that plots a degradation from green to red depending on the accuracy and the FFT of the received signal.

1) Here is the code for the image plot:

```
colormap(cmap);
imagesc(bmp,'Parent',handles.axes_tuner);
hold(handles.axes_tuner,'on');
% Vertical line in front of the image
plot([L/2,L/2],[-length(bmp(:,1)),2*length(bmp(:,1))],'b','LineWidth',1.5);
axis(handles.axes_tuner,'off');
hold(handles.axes_tuner,'off');
```

2) Plot on the other axes

```
cla(handles.axes_fft);
hold(handles.axes_fft,'on');
plot(f,spectrum,'b-','Parent',handles.axes_fft);
xlabel(handles.axes_fft,'Frequency','FontSize',8);
axis([0 Fs -50 0]);
ylabel(handles.axes_fft,'Normalized Amplitude','FontSize',8);
hold(handles.axes_fft,'off');
```

Comment: I'm not sure to get it... this line `cla(handles.axes_fft)` does indeed clear the axes and "restart" it

Comment: @Benoit_11 What I think he is saying is that when he's plotting on `handles.axes_fft`, `handles.axes_tuner` is cleared. I'm not really sure how, to be honest.

Comment: Are you sure this is all the code required to reproduce your issue?